# Create macro for different images in chapter title overlay using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, formatting, environments, chapters

I would like to make an image overlay of the chapter. So far I have found this code and it works if I specify the image directly in the definition:

```
\newcommand\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below right=4.8cm and 0cm of current page.north east] (a)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[fill overzoom image=
!!!!!!!!!!!!HERE IS THE IMAGE NAME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
]
 (current page.north west) rectangle
          (a);
        \node[below right=2.5cm and 2cm of current page.north
     west,color=blue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

However, I can not figure it out how to make it as a macro, namely, I want to put "#2" in the name of the picture as a placeholder and then I can pass a custom image name as an argument later.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I didn't check your code, but can't you store the two arguments in some macros, such as `\mytitleimagename` and then just change these (using `\renewcommand{\mytitleimagename}{my-image-name.jpg]` or so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you intend the output to look like as you did not provide a minimal working example but merely a code snippet. Anyways, you should avoid nesting `tikzpicture` environments.

As I suggested in my comment, why don't you just create a custom command `\myimagename` where you store the name of the current image? The same could work for the chapter label, however, I did not understand from your code how you intend to use this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec, tikz, tikzfill}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows}

\newcommand\mychapterlabel{}
\newcommand\myimagename{example-image-a}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate[below right=4.8cm and 0cm of current page.north east] (a);
    \fill[fill overzoom image=\myimagename] (current page.north west) rectangle (a);
    \node[below right=2.5cm and 2cm of current page.north west, color=blue]
        {\color{white}\chapterlabel\mychapterlabel};
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\mychapterlabel{Foo}
\chapter{One}

\renewcommand\mychapterlabel{Bar}
\renewcommand\myimagename{example-image-b}
\chapter{Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to write as little as possible. The appearance here was not important, rather the idea how to include multiple passing arguments in the command. Thanks!